# how to deduct time/date from current datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to deduct SOME datetime from current datetime.
That SOME is defined on few rules.

If current time is between 11:30 PM to 12:00 AM,deduct 11 hrs 30 min PM of the same day.
Else deduct 11 hrs 30 min PM till previous day.

Lets take a example.

if current time is April,23rd 11:45 PM,deduct till 11:30 Pm from same day which gives result of 15 min.

if current time is April,23rd 08:30 AM,deduct till 11:30 PM from previous day(22nd) which gives result 540 mins.

I am trying to deduct using DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).

But unable to code exact logic in c#.
Any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include some code sample or atleast psuedocode

Comment: You can use TimeSpan. + bit of easy logic.

Comment: @MajkeloDev could u please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

You will need to test this and it may need amending slightly but try working on this...

```
    TimeSpan eTs = new TimeSpan(23, 30, 00);
    double inMins;

    if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < eTs)
    {
        DateTime dTarget = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date + eTs;
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dTarget);
        inMins = ts.TotalMinutes;
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime dTarget = DateTime.Now.Date + eTs;
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dTarget);
        inMins = ts.TotalMinutes;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use your variable instead of DateTime.Today.
Like: `var newDate = SOMEDate.AddDays(-1);`